# Why is the variable "a" in this JavaScript statement not a variable expression?

Tags: javascript

In "Up & Going", the first book in Kyle Simpson's "You Don't Know JS" series, he presents the following statement, and explains that it contains ***four*** expressions:

```
a = b * 2;
```

He says that:

- ***2*** is a literal value expression
- ***b*** is a variable expression
- ***b*** * ***2*** is an arithmetic expression
- ***a = b*** * ***2*** is an assignment expression

All of which I agree with.

The Mozilla Developer Network defines an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) as ***any valid unit of code that resolves to a value***.

Is ***a*** not a variable expression because it is a LHS expression and being assigned to rather than evaluated?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: What @torazaburo said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, an expression is something which conforms to the syntax for an expression, and is treated as an expression because it appears in an expression context. It is  evaluated and results in a value.

For instance, `{}` is an expression indicating an empty object literal only in expression contexts; elsewhere it might be a block. The same holds for a syntactic construct starting with the `function` keyword.

In contrast, we normally don't think of the left hand side of assignments as being an "expression". Certainly, we could not write `a + 2 = 3`. Even when the left side **could** be considered an expression, such as `a` or `a.b`, we normally don't refer to it as an expression, because we think of expressions as being things that are evaluated, whereas such left hand sides are "references".

It is this common usage that the author of your book is following in not identifying `a` as an expression in `a = b * 2`.

However, the terminological waters are muddied somewhat by the names of the tokens used in the spec. The spec defines something called an *AssignmentExpression*, which is basically any expression like `2` or `a` or `a + 2` or `a = b` (which evaluates to `b`). So far so good. But it then proceeds to define something called *LeftHandSideExpression*, which obviously is what occurs on the left-hand side of an assignment (or to which `++` etc. is applied), but defines it as an `AssignmentExpression`. What? We can't put a `2` on the left-hand side, can we?  The spec addresses this by limiting what kinds of *AssignmentExpression*s can serve as *LeftHandSideExpression*s, excluding `2`, for example (since it is not a "IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget").

So it **is** correct to **not** call the `a` in `a = b * 2` an expression--in the common usage of the term "expression". But it is also technically correct to say that it **is** an expression, in the sense that that word is used in the spec, where it is a *LeftHandSideExpression*.

Comment: Just a note that *AssignmentExpression* is **almost any** expression. It excludes expressions that uses the comma operator. That's the only difference between *Expression* and *AssignmentExpression* non-terminal symbols basically. Also, Object literals and Array literals grammar can be used for LHS of assignment expressions even though `IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget` excludes them (different semantics though).

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense. `a` is a variable expression just as `b` is, and they both evaluate to variable references. Which are then used differently of course - the value of the `b` reference is being accessed, and a value is put into the `a` reference. Nonetheless, both identifiers form an expression.

This is a technicality however (and there isn't even an official term "variable expression"), and I guess it was omitted here for simplification purposes. Treating left-hand-sides as non-expressions breaks apart in more complex code, though.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, they are called [**Identifiers**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifiers) (or *IdentifierReference* if you use the non-terminal symbol name), not variable expressions and they evaluate to [**references**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type). LHS are also considered expressions. The grammar includes *NewExpressions*, *CallExpressions*, *MemberExpressions* and *PrimaryExpressions* (which Identifiers belong to). Assignment operator semantics won't allow for many of these expressions though.

So technically, `a` there is also an expression.